# n-Queens Problem: why the expression written next can assert there is at most one queen in each row if the expression is True?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I can't understand the expression although I have tried to understand it by making model.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of predicate `p(i,j)`?

Comment: p(i,j) is true when there is a queen on the square in the ith row and jth column and is false otherwise

Comment: Actually, I think it is not correct. j and k run over all pairs so the condition should be not p(i,j) or not p(i,k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is wrong. Consider the 2x2 case where the top row contains two queens and the bottom row is empty.

Then Q2 (which is supposed to assert there is at most 1 queen in each row) expands to:

```
(¬p(1, 1) ∨ ¬p(2, 1)) ∧
(¬p(2, 1) ∨ ¬p(2, 1))
```

Now the bottom row is empty so `¬p(2, 1)` is true, satisfying both conditions. This means that Q2 is satisfied when it shouldn't be.

---

If you're not convinced by the above expansion, run the following Python code to see for yourself:

```py
n = 2
for i in range(1, 1+n):
    for j in range(1, 1+(n-1)):
        for k in range(j+1, 1+n):
            print(f"!p({i}, {j}) v !p({k}, {j})")
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have see that with your help !